# Android app fail

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, android-app

I got an email from Stack Overflow Careers (might want to change that, with the switch to SO Jobs tab, another post) asking if I'm still actively looking (which I am, BTW). I tap the link at the bottom saying "yes, I'm looking", and Android asks me if I want to open in a browser or the Stack Exchange app. If I select the app, it opens, then closes, and nothing happens. Not even a "we can't show SO jobs in the app yet" message.

Feel free to edit the tags. I'm not sure if this is a bug, if the Jobs tab has yet to be implemented in the app (which would be nice, again another post), or if there are no plans to implement jobs in the app, and if there is some way to force browser only links.

Just saying, I tried the link on android, and it was a pain. The browser made me log in again, and I gave up there.

Comment: To my recollection, it's not implemented in the app.  It has always opened in your browser as opposed to being a part of the app.  In its defense, the app is largely based on the Stack Exchange API, and [it doesn't look like the API supports anything Careers/Jobs related](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).  Not yet, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed on version 1.0.79 and above (currently only on [our beta tier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262151/open-beta-testing-of-the-stack-exchange-android-app)) -- it's not the exact fix I wanted. Your phone will still ask if you want to open the link in the app, but if you do it'll recognize that it can't handle the link and immediately send you back to a browser.

The reason this happens is due to our URL (and and hostname) format, and how Android accepts URL filters. Because we're always adding new sites, the app is registered to accept URLs of the format `*.stackexchange.com` which gets us in some trouble since, for example, `chat.stackexchange.com` is a valid URL but not one that we support in the app. This is something we have checks for in the app's link dispatch handling logic, and I added another check for `/jobs` that does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Jobs on Stack Overflow is currently in Beta and hasn't been integrated with the Stack Exchange mobile apps yet, so those links have to be opened in a browser at this time.

Comment: IMO, The app should be fixed to not try to open things it can't open, ie. It should not show as an option when clicking an SO jobs link in another app.